# function inside another function using for statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my script.There is no errors in console, but there is no output. My code should create P elements inside Divs with class "example", but my divs with class "example" will be held in Divs with class "background".

So far i have that:
HTML:

```
<div class="background">
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="background">
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="background">
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="background">
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
<div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

}
.background {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;

}
```

JavaScript:

```
function background(){debugger;
var bg = document.getElementsByClassName("background");
var num;
for (var num=0; num < bg.length; num++ ){
    var line = bg[num].getElementsByClassName("example");
    var row ;
    for(var row=0; row < line.length; row++){
        var makeBoxInterval = setInterval(makeBoxes, 50);
        function makeBoxes(){

        var element =line[row].getElementsByClassName("num");
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        para.classList.add("num");
        var parent = line[row];
        var rowWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
        var boxesSoFar = element.length;
        var boxWidth = element.offsetWidth;
        var boxesInRow = rowWidth / boxWidth;
            if (boxesSoFar < boxesInRow) {
        parent.appendChild(para);
            } 
            else {
        clearInterval(makeBoxInterval);
         } 
    }
}
}
setInterval(function(){background()},100)
}

window.onload = function(){ 

  background();


}
```

i change my JavaScript  for:

```
function background(){debugger;
    var bg = document.getElementsByClassName("background");
    var num;
    for (let num=0; num < bg.length; num++ ){
        let line = bg[num].getElementsByClassName("example");
        let row ;
        for(let row=0; row < line.length; row++){
            let makeBoxInterval = setInterval(makeBoxes, 50);
            function makeBoxes(){

            let element =line[row].getElementsByClassName("num");
            let para = document.createElement("p");
            para.classList.add("num");
            let parent = line[row];
            let rowWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
            let boxesSoFar = element.length;
            let boxWidth = element.offsetWidth;
            let boxesInRow = rowWidth / boxWidth;
                if (boxesSoFar < boxesInRow) {
            parent.appendChild(para);
                } 
                else {
            clearInterval(makeBoxInterval);
             } 
        }
    }
    }
    setInterval(function(){background()},100)
    }

    window.onload = function(){ 

      background();


    }
```

But still nothing...

Any idea how to connect functions with for statements inside anouther function? or maybe there is some other way??

[fiddle:](https://fiddle.jshell.net/k32ofxzd/13/)

Comment: in the second for loop change num++ to row++

Comment: ahh.. damn.. o  ye now i have 1000 errors..

Comment: Declare your loop variables! And give them block scope: `for (let ....`.

Comment: There's a lot you need to change here.  I suggest you start by extending the interval timer, to say 2000ms, so that you'll be able to see what happens. The you need to move the function outside of the {} blocks, ie. it needs to be declared at the same time that the function is first run. Then the scope of line & row needs to be at the same level as the function, ie. top level declaration.

Comment: Did you look at the console? This code should produce errors in the console.

Comment: ye i change a code. I don't have any errors but still i don't have output...

Comment: Don't change the question based on information provided in the answer. That makes the answer look irrelevant. Please revert. You can always *add* something to the question.

Comment: i just add let, missing ; and change num for a row. To show others what i have now and where may be the issue that my code don't work. But ye, i will mark that on main question that i make some changes will give code before and after change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your internal function references `row` and `num` which by the time that function executes (asynchronously), have already reached their final values: this is because both loops will complete *before* any interval triggers the inner function. That will only start to happen after your loops have performed all iterations.

The same is true for other variables you reference in the function (e.g. `line`, `makeBoxInterval`): they are local to the outer function only, and thus the inner function will reference the latest value assigned to them.

To avoid this from happening, give your variables (which you should declare) a block scope, i.e. use `let`:

```
for (let num=0; num < bg.length; num++ ){
    let line = bg[num].getElementsByClassName("example");
    let row ;
    for(let row=0; row < line.length; row++){
        let makeBoxInterval = setInterval(makeBoxes, 50);
        // ...etc
```

Now the inner function will reference a `row` and `num` variable instances that are local to the proper iterations of the loops.

#### Other issues

You have several other issues in your code:

- `element` is a HTML element list, so it will not have a `offsetWidth` property. You probably wanted to get that from the first element: `element[0].offsetWidth`.
- You have two `setInterval` calls, which will stack up and eventually make your page hang. `setTimeout` is a safer method, as you then are responsible for calling a next `setTimeout`.
- Your loops are synchronous, yet you want to have asynchronous effects. In that case it is more practical to make an asynchronous loop, with a function that calls itself with the next parameters to use.
- Your CSS has absolute positioning, so all rows will appear on the same spot. That means that the effect of the growing second row will not have any visual consequence. I have not fixed this, as I don't know what your purpose is in visualisation. But it was not part of your question, and I think you should take it from here:

```js
function background(){
    const lines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".background>.example"));
    (function makeBoxInterval(row) {
        if (row >= lines.length) return; // all done
        const parent = lines[row],
            element = parent.getElementsByClassName("num"),
            para = document.createElement("p"),
            rowWidth = parent.offsetWidth,
            boxesSoFar = element.length,
            boxWidth = boxesSoFar ? element[0].offsetWidth : 1,
            boxesInRow = rowWidth / boxWidth;
        para.classList.add("num");
        if (boxesSoFar < boxesInRow) {
            parent.appendChild(para);
            setTimeout(makeBoxInterval.bind(null, row), 500);
        } else {
            makeBoxInterval(row+1);
        }
    })(0);
}

window.onload = background;
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.background {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  color: orange;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
    <div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="background">
    <div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
    <div class="example"><p class="num"></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i change most of variables expect 1st two for let but still not working. [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/k32ofxzd/18/) i know that my questions are silly but i'm on beginning with my journey with IT. what else i can do?

Comment: See addition to my answer. You have many issues in your code. I fixed it up to some point. For you to take it from here.